# How does 'String#gsub { }' (with a block) work?

Tags: ruby, string

When I do,

```
> "fooo".gsub("o") {puts "Found an 'o'"}
Found an 'o'
Found an 'o'
Found an 'o'
=> "f"
```

`gsub` removes all `'o'`s. How does this work?

I think `gsub` passes each character to the block, but since block is doing nothing to the character itself (like catching it), it is dropped.

I think this is the case because, when I do

```
> "fooo".gsub("o"){|ch| ch.upcase}
=> "fOOO"
```

the block is catching the character and turning it into uppercase. 
But when I do,

```
> "fooo".gsub("o", "u"){|ch| ch.upcase}
=> "fuuu"
```

How does Ruby handle the block in this case?

I found that Ruby plugs the blocks into methods using `yield`. (check [this](https://mixandgo.com/blog/mastering-ruby-blocks-in-less-than-5-minutes)) But I am still not sure about my explanation for the first code example and third example. Can anyone put some more light on this?

Comment: `gsub` should indeed print a warning if both, a second argument and a block is given.

Comment: @Stefan why should this be the case? Any method can accept a block should every method print this warning?

Comment: @engineersmnky if the block argument is part of the method's public API, yes. Just like `[].index(1) {}` or `[].fetch(1,0) {}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation of method [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) explains how it works, depending of what parameters it gets:

> `gsub(pattern, replacement)` → `new_str`
>   `gsub(pattern, hash)` → `new_str`
>   `gsub(pattern) {|match| block }` → `new_str`
>   `gsub(pattern)` → `enumerator`
>
> Returns a copy of *str* with *all* occurrences of *pattern* substituted for the second argument. The *pattern* is typically a [`Regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html); if given as a [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html), any regular expression metacharacters it contains will be interpreted literally, e.g. `\\d` will match a backslash followed by `d`, instead of a digit.
>
> If *replacement* is a `String` it will be substituted for the matched text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups of the form `\\d`, where `d` is a group number, or `\\k<n>`, where `n` is a group name. If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must be preceded by an additional backslash. However, within replacement the special match variables, such as `$&`, will not refer to the current match.
>
> If the second argument is a [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html), and the matched text is one of its keys, the corresponding value is the replacement string.
>
> In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a parameter, and variables such as `$1`, `$2`, `` $` ``, `$&`, and `$'` will be set appropriately. The value returned by the block will be substituted for the match on each call.
>
> The result inherits any tainting in the original string or any supplied replacement string.
>
> When neither a block nor a second argument is supplied, an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html) is returned.

The answer to your question looks straightforward now.
When only one argument is passed (the *pattern*), *"the value returned by the block will be substituted for the match on each call"*.

Two arguments **and** a block is a case not covered by the documentation because it is not a valid combination. It seems that when two arguments are passed, `String#gsub` doesn't expect a block and ignores it.

### Update

The purpose of [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) is to do a "global search", i.e. find all occurrences of some string or pattern and replace them.

The first argument, *pattern*, is the string or pattern to search for. There is nothing special about it. It can be a string or a regular expression. `String#gsub` searches it and finds zero or more matches (occurrences).

With only one argument and no block, `String#gsub` returns an iterator because it can find the pattern but it doesn't have a replacement string to use.

There are three ways to provide it the replacements for the matches (the first three cases described in the documentation quoted above):

1. a *String* is used to replace all the matches; it is usually used to remove parts from a string (by providing the empty string as replacement) or mask fragments of it (credit card numbers, passwords, email addresses etc);
2. a *Hash* is used to provide different replacements for each match; it is useful when the matches are known in advance;
3. a *block* is provided when the replacements depend on the matched substrings but the matches are not known in advance; for example, a block can convert each matching substring to uppercase and return it to let `String#gsub` use it as replacement.

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks ! I have been through the documentation but somehow missed that line. I will accept this as answer.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that the second argument supersedes the block, does it?

Comment: @Stefan indeed, the documentation doesn't say anything about the combination of two arguments and a block. I reformulated that paragraph in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The return value of `puts` is `nil`, which is converted to blank by `to_s`. Hence, each matched `"o"` is replaced with blank.

Comment: Another example: ` "fooo".gsub("o") { [1,2,3] } #=> "f[1, 2, 3][1, 2, 3][1, 2, 3]"`, as [Array#to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-to_s) is applied to the array in the block.

Comment: @sawa, so there's no passing of characters to the block in the first example ? And is the block ignored in third example ?

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks! I am more interested in how it works. 
sawa provides good explanation but it still doesn't completely answer my question.